# playing video using monkeyrunner

Tags: android, video, monkeyrunner

I am playing a mp4 file using monkeyrunner's startactivity function,it is working.Now,i want to know whether the video is still playing or has ended.But,as monkeyrunner doesn't wait for the video(or any other activity)to finish or say "return".How to know whether the video finished or not?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to look at the android debug log in a sub-process. Hopefully the app that you are using to play the mp4 will have some type of log output when it finishes playing the file.

Answer (score 0):

If you play the video file with the Gallery app, when you start playing the file, the logcat will show:

*Displayed com.android.gallery3d/.app.MovieActivity*

After the app finishes playing the file, the logcat will show:

*Displayed com.android.gallery3d/.app.Gallery*

You can look for these strings in the logcat.

As a side note, there are some system properties that you can check using monkeyrunner:

```
device.getProperty('am.current.package')
device.getProperty('am.current.action')
```

These show the package name of the currently running package and the current activity's action. Unfortunately when i used them, they returned a blank string, not the names I wanted.

I hope this is useful.

Comment: Logcat is not showing Displayed com.android.gallery3d/.app.MovieActivity

Comment: Then try to use 'am.current.package', 'am.current.action'

Comment: both are returning blank strings

Comment: Try starting your app with device.startActivity(component = package/activity). It works for me. When I manually start the app, am.current returns blank strings in my case too.